# Calculating the average and standard deviation of the opening, highest, lowest and closing prices in the past 5 days with daily OHLC data

Tags: dolphindb

With daily OHLC data, can I calculate the average and standard deviation of the opening, highest, lowest and closing prices in the past 5 days (20 values in total)? More specifically, can you perform moving window calculation on multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

Break down the calculation formula and create a user-defined function to calculate the averages and standard deviations:

```
def std_ohlc(open, close, high, low){
    count = mcount(close,5)+mcount(open,5)+mcount(high,5)+mcount(low,5)
    avg = (msum(close, 5)+msum(open, 5)+msum(low, 5)+msum(high, 5))\count
    sum2 = msum(close*close, 5)+msum(open*open, 5)+msum(high*high , 5)+msum(low*low, 5)
    return sqrt((sum2 -count* square(avg))\(count-1)), avg
}
```

New function `msum2` has been added since version 1.30.19/2.00.7. The line with `sum2` in the script above can be adjusted with `msum2(close,5)`.

Test this function:

```
bar = table(take(2020.01.01..2020.01.10,20) as tradedate, rand(10.0,20) as open, rand(10.0,20) as close, rand(10.0,20) as high, rand(10.0,20) as low, take(`a,10) join take(`b,10) as id)
```

---

```
select id, open, close , high, low, std_ohlc(open, close, high, low) as `std`avg from bar context by id
```

output:

[image]